# terraform variable default value interpolation from locals

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a use case where I need two AWS providers for different resources. The default `aws` provider is configured in the main module which uses another module that defines the additional `aws` provider.

By default, I'd like both providers to use the same AWS credentials unless explicitly overridden.

I figured I could do something like this. In the main module:

```
locals {
  foo_cloud_access_key = aws.access_key
  foo_cloud_secret_key = aws.secret_key
}

variable "foo_cloud_access_key" {
  type        = string
  default     = local.foo_cloud_access_key
}

variable "foo_cloud_secret_key" {
  type        = string
  default     = local.foo_cloud_secret_key
}
```

where `variable`s `foo_cloud_secret_key` and `foo_cloud_access_key` would then be passed down to the child module like this:

```
module foobar {
...
  foobar_access_key = var.foo_cloud_access_key
  foobar_secret_key = var.foo_cloud_secret_key
...
}
```

Where `module foobar` would then configure its additional was provide with these variables:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias      = "foobar_aws"
  access_key = var.foobar_access_key
  secret_key = var.foobar_secret_key
}
```

When I run the init `terraform` spits out this error (for both variables):

```
Error: Variables not allowed
  on variables.tf line 66, in variable "foo_cloud_access_key":
  66:   default     = local.foo_cloud_access_key

Variables may not be used here.
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this in `terraform` or is there any other way to go about this?

Answer (score 7):

Having complex, computed default values of variables is possible, but only with a workaround:

- define a dummy default value for the variable, e.g. `null`
- define a local variable, its value is either the value of the variable or the actual default value

```
variable "something" {
    default = null
}

locals {
    some_computation = ... # based on whatever data you want
    something = var.something == null ? local.some_computation : var.something
}
```

And then only only use `local.something` instead of `var.something` in the rest of the terraform files.

Comment: Note, that I need to "extract" *provider* config variables and use them elsewhere i.e. aws provider will be configured with `access_key` and `secret_key` and I need to use those as default values in other variables.

Comment: You can also use the coalesce function to make it cleaner: `coalesce(var.something, local.something)`. I also encourage to add descriptions that show what is default is.