# 'Variables not allowed' error when trying to retrieve rds endpoint and store it in AWS secret manager via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use Terraform to manage part of the secret to store the database credentials.
Following this page: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret_version
I'm trying to define four key-value pairs:

```
variable "example_string" {
  default = {
    engine = "mysql"
    port = "xxxx"
    host = aws_rds_cluster.example_rds_cluster.endpoint
    dbClusterIdentifier = local.db_name
  }

  type = map(string)
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "example_secret_string" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example_secret.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(var.example_string)
}
```

When I try to apply Terraform, it gave me error:

```
Error: Variables not allowed

  on ..\..\terraform\secret_manager.tf line 31, in variable "example_string":
  31:     host = aws_rds_cluster.example_rds_cluster.endpoint

Variables may not be used here.


Error: Variables not allowed

  on ..\..\terraform\secret_manager.tf line 32, in variable "example_string":
  32:     dbClusterIdentifier = local.db_name

Variables may not be used here.
```

Does that mean I can only define strings but I can't reference other stuff defined in `locals` or other terraform resources? Or am I missing anything? Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use anything dynamic within the `default` block of variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [terraform variable default value interpolation from locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66284854/terraform-variable-default-value-interpolation-from-locals)

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 But is there any other way to pass dynamic strings to secret?

Comment: Yes, use the workaround in the suggested duplicate. Or do not use a dynamic default value in the first place.

Comment: Appart from other comments, you should be aware that any such secret of yours will be in plain text in TF state file. So depending on your security policies, this could be acceptable or not.